# NTLM/ActiveDirectory entry creation gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a Ruby gem that enables easy creation/modification of Active Directory entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the gem `ruby-ldap` that has support for common LDAP libraries like OpenLDAP, UMich LDAP, Netscape SDK and Active Directory (as it says in http://ruby-ldap.sourceforge.net/).

You can install it with `gem install ruby-ldap`

You can make changes in entries using the `LDAP::Record` class (http://ruby-ldap.sourceforge.net/rdoc/classes/LDAP/Record.html#M000060)